# How can i rotate object in animation clip loop and how to set and change the speed in script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created animation clip of 4 seconds that show the propeller rotating few times.
Then i checked the Loop Pose so it's true now.

The problem is that when it's getting to second 4 it stop and then start the clip over again. How can i make smooth looping so it will not stop in the end ?

This is how i start the animation clip in script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator _anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        _anim.CrossFade("Propeller001", 0);
    }
}
```

And after fixing the problem i want to add StartCoroutine to the script to set the speed. I want to make something like motion blur effect when rotating the propellers.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your animation window, make sure the animation ends precisely on the last frame. Unity has the tendency not to update the animation cycle duration properly when the frame rate is changed.

If the animation duration is wrong, you may have to add a frame at the proper duration point, and then delete it.